# Time complexity when checking deque is empty

Tags: python

When I want to check whether **deque** is empty in python, I usually use this code snippet.

```
from collections import deque

q = deque()

# iterate until deque is empty
while q:
   do something...
```

I wonder how the time complexity is when checking whether the deque is empty. 
Does it take **O(n)**?

Is there any faster way to check whether deque is empty?

Comment: Time Complexity for len(q) is O(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. `while q` is essentially `while len(q)`, and the time complexity of `deque.__len__` is O(1).